# vimrc Line Placing me In Replace Mode

Tags: vimrc, replace

I have the following one-line `~/.vimrc` file:

Line 1/1: `nnoremap <silent> <ESC> :nohlsearch<CR><ESC>`

Whenever I edit a new document, now, I am placed immediately in Replace mode after opening the file (`vim file.txt` opens the file in Vim placing me directly in replace mode). Does anyone know what might be happening (I have included my Vim version below for more information).

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan  2 2014 19:39:32)
Included patches: 1-52
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian. Compiled by buildd@

Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):

+acl             +farsi           +mouse_netterm   +syntax
+arabic          +file_in_path    +mouse_sgr       +tag_binary
+autocmd         +find_in_path    -mouse_sysmouse  +tag_old_static
-balloon_eval    +float           +mouse_urxvt     -tag_any_white
-browse          +folding         +mouse_xterm     -tcl
++builtin_terms  -footer          +multi_byte      +terminfo
+byte_offset     +fork()          +multi_lang      +termresponse
+cindent         +gettext         -mzscheme        +textobjects
-clientserver    -hangul_input    +netbeans_intg   +title
-clipboard       +iconv           +path_extra      -toolbar
+cmdline_compl   +insert_expand   -perl            +user_commands
+cmdline_hist    +jumplist        +persistent_undo +vertsplit
+cmdline_info    +keymap          +postscript      +virtualedit
+comments        +langmap         +printer         +visual
+conceal         +libcall         +profile         +visualextra
+cryptv          +linebreak       +python          +viminfo
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +vreplace
+cursorbind      +listcmds        +quickfix        +wildignore
+cursorshape     +localmap        +reltime         +wildmenu
+dialog_con      -lua             +rightleft       +windows
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
+digraphs        +mksession       +scrollbind      -X11
-dnd             +modify_fname    +signs           -xfontset
-ebcdic          +mouse           +smartindent     -xim
+emacs_tags      -mouseshape      -sniff           -xsmp
+eval            +mouse_dec       +startuptime     -xterm_clipboard
+ex_extra        +mouse_gpm       +statusline      -xterm_save
+extra_search    -mouse_jsbterm   -sun_workshop    -xpm
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
    user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
    user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H     -g -O2 -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -Wformat -Werror=format-security -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1      
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl    -L/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython2.7 -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -Xlinker -export-dynamic -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions `
```

Comment: I remember seeing a related comment here: https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/102#issuecomment-45413916. Maybe you can just use the InsertLeave autocommand instead of that mapping?

Comment: vim communicates the the terminal using escape sequences. Mapping escape breaks those escape sequences. Solution. Don't map escape.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mapping anything to <kbd>Esc</kbd> is a really bad idea.  I suggest someyhing like this instead:

```
nnoremap <M-\>  :set hlsearch!<CR><Bar>:echo 'hlsearch: ' . {0:'Off', 1:'On'}[&hlsearch]<CR>
```

Here <kbd>Meta</kbd>-<kbd>\</kbd> toggles `hlsearch`.

Comment: I feel like `{0:'Off', 1:'On'}[&hlsearch]` reads better than `strpart`

Comment: Although you do realize that `nohlsearch` does something different from `set nohlsearch`?

Comment: @FDinoff: To be honest, I copied that part from somewhere else many years ago, without giving it much though.  But you're right, of course; I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @FDinoff: _"`nohlsearch` does something different from `set nohlsearch`"_ - Yes, but I think toggling `hlsearch` is far more useful.

Comment: You guys were totally right. Mapping to escape is a bad idea. I ended up changing the command to `nnoremap <silent> <Leader>\` :let @/=""<CR>`. This clears the search register - it does **not** set the search register to an empty string as that would match everywhere.  Doing this sets up the search register in the same state as when vim starts (I like that). I got the idea from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/657447/vim-clear-last-search-highlighting). I'm sorry I didn't see it there first. I did look around before I posted (posting takes up my time, too). Thanks very much, all.